# Pdf syntax for showing external file

Tags: pdf, syntax

I'm learning pdf syntax, and I need to import an external text file to show its content on a page. How do I do that?
For now I just know about

```
<< /Type /Filespec /F (/path/to/file) >>
```

structure, but have no idea how to use it.
The resources I m using now [https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/pdf_reference_archives/PDFReference.pdf]
[https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf]

Comment: *"I need to import an external text file to show its content on a page"* - That is not really a thing PDF was designed for.

Comment: Frankly speaking, it's for bugbounty purposes)

Comment: Ah ;) Ok. Well, unfortunately I've not yet looked into importing external parts, in particular not into what security restrictions there are in common PDF viewers for such imports. What I would look into first, would probably be external streams (ISO 32000-1 Table 5 – Entries common to all stream dictionaries, entries F, FFilter, FDecodeParams), reference XObjects (ISO 32000-1, section 8.10.4), and JavaScript.

Comment: ye, those are open in my browser. but having looked a couple of times through them I still can't understand how to embed/referense a particular file. There is no exact syntax example of that. At least I don't understand or don't see it.

Comment: oh, @mkl it's you from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36318312/pdf-with-an-external-image-using-xobject )
That part with the image that you showed, so is there anything similar to any other file?

Comment: It was mentioned in https://pdf-insecurity.org/pdf-dangerous-paths/attacks.html But no exaples of using the importing.

Comment: Oops, I haven't seen the new article on pdf-insecurity. I'll have a look. Thanks for the pointer. But unfortunately it's indeed as mentioned above, except in the answer you found I haven't dug into external references. But in the context of the answer - if it suffices to reference an external JPEG, have a look at ISO 32000-1 section 8.9.5.4; this is an example of an external stream by the way.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227552/discussion-between---and-mkl).

Comment: As you had mentioned the pdf-insecurity.org "Dangerous Paths" - why don't you simply download their *Exploits*? There are PDFs with reference XObjects among them...